# Callback after successful firebase login

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase with angular fire for a simple app. Using Facebook Authentication. Code looks like this:

```
$scope.signUser = function () {
  Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook', function(error, authData){
    if (error) {
      console.log("Login Error:", error);
    } else {
      console.log(authData.facebook.accessToken);
    }
  });
};
```

The login works fine. However I can't get the else statement to throw back anything to the console on successful login.

How can I get it to return the access token / run a callback function on successful login?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't really. Are you saying that `console.log(authData.facebook.accessToken);` doesn't print anything in the JavaScript console? If so, does `console.log('Hello, someone authenticated');` print?

Comment: Nothing prints @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: But it logs in fine @FrankvanPuffelen it's just the callback which isn't working.

Comment: before the `if` statement, what values are returned as `error` and `authData` on successful login?